# Javascript return doesn't work? returns undefined

Tags: jquery, json, function, javascript

I got a wierd issue with a javascript script.

This is my code:

```
function checkDiscountCode()
{

  var discountCode = $('#korcode').val();
  var errorMessage = $('#errorMessage').text();

  if(discountCode.length > 2)
  {

     $.getJSON( 'calc.php?code=' + discountCode, function( json ) 
     {    
       var color = json.color; 
       var soort = json.soort;
       var waarde = json.waarde; 
       var message = json.message;

       if(errorMessage != message)
       {
          $('#error').html('<font color="' + color + '" id="errorMessage">' + message + '</font>');
       }

       if(message == 'OK!')
       {
          var outputData = soort + '-' + waarde;
          console.log('outputData = ' + outputData);
          return outputData;
       }

     });   
  }   
}
```

The console log give the right data, for example 0-12.00 but when I request this function in another function, for example just a alert(checkDiscountCode()); it says undefined..

Can anyone please help me? I don't see the issue..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you're alerting, is `discountCode.length > 2` true? That's likely the problem.

Comment: @Purmou and I are thinking the same thing.  The difference in your observations may be when the function is being called, in relation to when the page is loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 8):

Your `checkDiscountCode()` function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined` by default.

The `return` statement that you've included is inside the anonymous function passed as a callback for `$.getJSON()`, so it returns from *that* function back to the jQuery code that called it, not back to *your* code (and even then it returns undefined if `message` is not `'OK!'`). (Also your `$.getJSON()` doesn't run unless `discountCode.length > 2`, though your `checkDiscountCode()` function doesn't try to return a value either way.)

Answer (score 2):

You're returning from a callback passed to a function that does work *asynchronously*. You'll have to adapt the code to take a callback and change the caller to deal with the fact that it's asynchronous.

That means that rather than this:

```
// won't work
function checkSomething() {
    someAsynchronousFunction(function(result) {
        return result == "success";
    });
}
if(checkSomething()) {
    alert("It worked.");
}else{
    alert("It didn't work.");
}
```

You'll have to change your code to look like this:

```
function checkSomething(callback) {
    someAsynchronousFunction(function(result) {
        callback(result == "success");
    });
}
checkSomething(function(result) {
    if(result) {
        alert("It worked.");
    }else{
        alert("It didn't work.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this with no result, I have a funtion:
[code]
checkDiscountCode(function(outputData) {
 alert(outputData);
 });
[/code]
to get this data and I set the data with
[code]
function checkDiscountCode(callback)
{


         callback(outputData);
[/code]

(ofc only pieces of the code)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works perfectly, that schema is very useful. Is there any link to read the doc about synchronous and asynchronous functions in JS ?

Comment: @Joe: JavaScript, unlike many other languages, doesn't really have official documentation. There is, however, another question here on Stack Overflow practically identical to this one with [a very good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) you may want to read explaining the reasons *why* the problem occurs (something I didn't really elaborate on here) and how to fix it.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks a lot, it's perfect both your answer for a quick understanding and the link for a wide knowledge of sync/async calls in JS. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `discountCode.length > 2` is not true, you aren't returning a value, thus it will return undefined.

---

I'll also add that if you did put it in another function `alert(checkDiscountCode())` and you closed firebug up, or opened in another browser that doesn't have console open, your browser will encounter a javascript error, if you left the `console.log(...)` line still in your code.

A console window has to be open in order to log to it.

Comment: It will also return that when it > 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's getJSON() method runs asynchronously. You should add a callback function to checkDiscountCode(); the callback function will run the rest of your app's logic. For example:

```
function sampleCallback(outputData) {
  console.log('outputData = ' + outputData);
}

function checkDiscountCode(callback) {
  $.getJSON( 'calc.php?code=' + discountCode, function( json ) {
    // get output data, and then call callback.
    callback(outputData);
  });
}

checkDiscountCode(sampleCallback);
```

Comment: Should I also return something?? I tried this methode but it didn't work.

Comment: I modified the code snippet to show what a callback would look like.

Answer (score 0):

And if `discountCode.length > 2` you are invoking the `$.getJSON` function, but that takes a callback, and returns nothing immediately.  Hence, in either case, you get `undefined`.